# Azure Sphere Doesn't send telemetry to Iot central IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_NO_NETWORK

Tags: c, azure, azure-iot-central, azure-sphere

Hello I'm trying to run the MT3620 AzureIot sample to send data from my azure sphere MT3620 (Mini-devboard) to my Azure Iot Central.

I followed all the steps of the tutorial: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sphere-samples/tree/master/Samples/AzureIoT#run-the-sample-with-iot-central

But after sending the data I got (in the output window):

```
IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_NO_NETWORK
```

and I don't get anything on my IotCentral :(

I executed the dev wifi show-status and the device is connected to my mobile hotspot

What does that mean? Thanks!

```
IoT Hub Authenticated: IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_NO_NETWORK
INFO: Message received by IoT Hub. Result is: 1
IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_CreateWithAzureSphereDeviceAuthProvisioning returned 'AZURE_SPHERE_PROV_RESULT_OK'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was a network problem.
I changed network and run ShowIotCentral and got the right connection string to use in allowedConnections

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved after changing the network. I hope suggestion provided on the MSDN helped resolved this issue. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6d05f3f1-347c-4aaf-aa9d-b375b82facc5/azure-sphere-doesnt-send-telemetry-to-iot-central-iothubclientconnectionnonetwork?forum=azuresphere

Comment: The `IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_NO_NETWORK` is returned when given IoT HUB is not added to `app_manifest.json`'s `AllowedConnections` key.